# auto trigger resque worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I want to auto trigger resque worker.
The usual way is that we invoke the resque operation

```
klass = Resque.reserve(:goutham_queue)
klass.perform if klass.respond_to? :perform
```

Is there a way to auto trigger the worker as soon as there is a item in resque queue.

Other than resque is there a system where event based triggering can be achived(event is a new entry in queue)... rather than poling the queue in intervals with a demon.